# DataTable createdRow isn't adding attribute to the rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatable

I'm trying to add `data-foo` attribute to each row of my DataTable. I need this attribute for sorting data however I tried the below but it's not adding the defined attribute

```
cx.common.data.cxAdminDataTables.EbFaqCategory = $CxRecordsTable.cxAdminDataTable({
    ajaxUrl: '<?php echo $this->CxHelper->Route('eb-admin-get-general-faq-categories')?>',
    // Per-row function to iterate cells
    "createdRow": function (row, data, rowIndex) {
        // Per-cell function to do whatever needed with cells
        $.each($('tr', row), function (colIndex) {
            // For example, adding data-* attributes to the cell
            $(this).attr('data-foo', "bar");
        });
    },
    columns: [
        cx.common.admin.tableEditColumn('id', { delete: true }),
        { data: 'category_name' },
        { data: 'faq_order' },
        cx.common.admin.tableDateColumn('date_created')
    ]
});
```

**My View Code:**

```
<table id="cx-records-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered faq-categories-table" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th class="hasinput">
                <input type="text" class="form-control filter" placeholder="Name">
            </th>
            <th class="hasinput">
                <input type="text" class="form-control filter" placeholder="Order">
            </th>
            <th class="hasinput">
                <input type="text" class="form-control filter" placeholder="Date Created">
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th class="all">Name</th>
            <th class="all">Order</th>
            <th class="all">Date Created</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**Js:**

```
var $sortable = $( ".faq-categories-table > tbody" );
$sortable.sortable({
    stop: function ( event, ui ) {
        var parameters = $sortable.sortable( "toArray");
        console.log(parameters);
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $this->CxHelper->Route('eb-admin-change-general-faq-category-order')?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { value: parameters },
            success: function (data) {
                cx.common.data.cxAdminDataTables.EbFaqCategory.cxAdminDataTable("reloadAjax");
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: did you try to console.log $(this) in your $.each ? Isn't `$.each($(row)` enough to iterate over your cells ?

Comment: what do you get if you console.log `$(this)` in the `each` function? I think the use of the second parameter here `$('tr', row)` could be incorrect, as it would try to find tr tags **inside** row

Comment: @Kaddath it prints nothing in console. I think it's not calling it!

Comment: @BernardPagoaga it prints nothing in console when i added console.log($(this));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.each($('tr', row)` will not work, because `row` is already a `tr` tag, and using `$` with a second parameter will restrict the selection **inside** the context as a second argument. There is no `tr` inside the `tr`, so your selection is empty.

try simply with:

```
"createdRow": function (row, data, rowIndex) {
    // Per-cell function to do whatever needed with cells
    $(row).attr('data-foo', "bar");
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still it's not adding the `data-foo` attribute. Even I added a console test but it's not being called! Check @ https://imgur.com/kYx3Nr4

Comment: do you mean the function `createdRow` is not called at all? that's another problem then..

Comment: Yes It's not printing the message in console which I added and it's not adding attribute to the tr!

Comment: Thanks for helping mate, issue was in our custom dataTable plugin. We didn't configured `createdRow` option. Once I defined it, it started working :)